# Is there a way to read Spring Security metadata?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring security and I have a custom Authorization Filter without explicit URL mapping. I have added my Authorization filter after UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class.

The problem with this approach is, even for the URL patterns which are either permitted or permitted with authentication are going through my Authorization Filter. I do not want to explicitly configure my filter mapping on Authorization Filter since I feel that is redundant(already present in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter). Is there anyway I can get access to Spring Security metadata or any other way to skip the Authorization Filter for the URLs which are marked as permitAll() or authenticated()?

```
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {

    public void destroy() {

    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

        //Calls a webservice to fetch the authorities based on the URL pattern.
        //Adds the authentication principal with Authorities to SecurityContextHolder.
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your custom filter ?

Comment: @chaoluo I have added my Authorization Filter and in comments specified what it will try accomplishing.

Comment: I think you can inject your own request matcher to this filter to skip these urls

Comment: Yes. That works. But I would like to use the spring security HttpSecurity configuration itself to do that. I think I found a way. I can register an ObjectPostProcessor and extract securityMetadataSource information from FilterSecurityInterceptor. Thanks for the quick response @chaoluo.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by extending WebExpressionVoter as below:

```
public class CustomAuthoritiesVoter extends WebExpressionVoter {

    private static final String SUPPORTED_CLASS = "org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionConfigAttribute";


    @Override
    public int vote(Authentication authentication, FilterInvocation fi, Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
        String exp = getExpressionString(attributes);

        if (null != exp && !StringUtils.equalsAny(exp, "authenticated", "permitAll")) {
            //Call service to fetch the authorities based on the userID and URL
            //Set Authentication principal along with fetched Authorities using SecurityContextHolder
        }

        return super.vote(authentication, fi, attributes);
    }

    private String getExpressionString(Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
        try {
            for (ConfigAttribute attribute : attributes) {
                if (attribute.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Class.forName(SUPPORTED_CLASS))) {
                    return attribute.toString();
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            log.warn(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```